# Weird color scheme in Azure ML Studio notebooks

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

I am getting this weird color scheme in Azure ML Studio. The code runs fine, but the excessive use of red makes it look like I have errors on every line. Anyone know how to change the theme?

[image: Printscreen]

Answer (score -1):

The color schemes are the default status indicators: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks#status-indicators)

But we can change the color schemes. Checkout the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/change-indicator-icons-and-indicator-sets-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16#to-change-the-color-of-an-indicator-icon) which leads to change the color of status indicators.

Comment: I am talking about the text color. You first link is about the status [indicator for the cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/media/how-to-run-jupyter-notebooks/command-mode.png).